# Using a StringBuilder variable in LINQ Method

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use a StringBuilder variable to query all of the selected years from my database. How can I get it to iterate through all the years and grab all the years from my database?

Here is my StringBuilder :

```
StringBuilder selectedYears = new StringBuilder();
foreach ( var item in years)
{
    selectedYears.Append(item + ",").ToString();
}
```

I am then using it in my LINQ method to query the DB but I can only query one year. So I tried StringBuilder but I don't know if I am going about his the right way. Here is my LINQ Method:

```
List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                     .Where(x => x.accountNum == acctNums && 
                     x.statementYear==selectedYears.ToString() 
                     && x.statementMonth == month)
                     .Select(c => c.statementPath).ToList();
```

When debugging I have a list of years on selectYears. but can't get it to read more than one year in my LINQ Method.

Comment: Your where-clause compares the statementYear to the entire list of years you have produced. That does not seem to be your intention. Are you trying to see if the statementYear is one of the ones in the list?

Comment: Have you tried `.Where(x => years.Contains(x.statementYear)`?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so the years will be whatever the user checks so it could only be one year or it could be 9 years. I then want to grab files from the db thats associated with those years.

Comment: @RufusL thank you! that is working the way i want!

Answer (score 0):

@RufusL has given me the correct way to write my method.

```
.Where(x => x.accountNum == acctNums && 
            years.Contains(x.statementYear) && 
            months.Contains(x.statementMonth))
```

This is giving me the desired files and output i was looking for.